# WP All import sale price 0

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, xml

I want to import woocommerce products from an xml file, i got a problem, with the sale price. In the provided xml some products sale price is “0,00”.

I would like to skip theese cases, and import the sale price only to products what have a real sale price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an IF statement like this to import a blank value in the case that the real value is “0,00”:

```
 [IF({saleprice[1][.="0,00"]})][ELSE].      {saleprice[1]}[ENDIF]
```

Just be sure to change “saleprice” to the correct element name from your file.